# Chips Autocomplete sin duplicar en Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, ts

Alguien que me ayude estoy aprendiendo a usar angular y angular material y estoy tratando de hacer que solo se muestre una etiqueta por cada valor sin que se vuelvan a repitan

```
  selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
   const arr = this.allFruits;
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      for (let l = j + 1; l < arr.length; l++) {
        if (arr[j] == arr[l]) {
          console.log('Array con los valores repetidos');
          console.log('array2' + arr[l]);
          this.fruits.push(event.option.viewValue);
        } else {
          alert('algo salio mal');
        }
      }
    }

    // this.fruits.push(event.option.viewValue);
    this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
  }
}
```

*aqui dejo el proyecto en un editor de codigo online* https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwfhdz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.html

Comment: puedes poner alguna referencia de lo que quieres obtener porfavor.

Comment: me requiero a que quiero que se muestre únicamente una vez lo que hay en mi arreglo

Comment: realmente no se entiende, puedes probar poniendo una foto de lo que obtienes y lo que quieres realmente.

Answer (score 0):

Yo realizaría lo siguiente:

```
selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
  const fruit = event.option.viewValue; // Nueva fruta

  // Si NO incluye la nueva fruta la agrega
  if (!this.fruits.includes(fruit)) {
    // Al agregarla activa el data-binding agregándola al templete por medio de la directiva *ngFor
    this.fruits.push(fruit);
  }

  // Si la fruta ya existe, no realiza ninguna acción
}
```

[documentación .includes() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)